# Excel: if cell value increases -> play sound

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a cell in excel that increases randomly through the day. This is an API from my trading platform which counts the total number of trades a day.

What I need to do is the following:

Build an IF statement that each time this cell value increases it plays a sound.
I have the sound part covered with a Macro I found online. But the IF statement is giving me trouble.

Anyone could help me out?

Comment: What triggers a change in the cell's value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the `Calculate()` event, depending on how the update occurs this may work for you. This needs to be placed in the **worksheet's** code module - NOT a standard module.

```
Option Explicit

Private priorVal As Currency

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Rem Change this range to be the range that needs to be looked at
    If Range("A1") <> priorVal Then
        Beep
        priorVal = Range("A1")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you missing `.Value` on the end of the ranges?

Comment: @Brotato `.Value` is the default and as such not necessary.

Comment: What triggers the Calculate event? I haven't used it before.

Comment: Anytime the worksheet does a calculation, this even will fire. It's more reliable then the `Change()` event because Change doesn't always fire - mainly when updated via code.

Comment: `Rem` comments now? ;-)

Comment: @ScottCraner except if it's parameterized, then `.Item` is the default... the default member is actually `Range.[_Default]`, a hidden property few VBA devs know about. I would argue that explicit code that *says what it does and does what it says* is better code - hence I would add the explicit `.Value` call (or `.Value2`?), *and* an explicit `Me.` qualifier in front of the `Range` calls.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Fair point and is my practice as well,  more to do with my OCD than any other reason. My point is that in this instance it would work with or without the `.Value`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs thank you for your answer! Would you mind telling me where is the code module? I have trouble identifying it within VBA. I tried putting it under ThisWorkbook but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Topli It would be `Sheet##` (Not `ThisWorkbook` - almost there) - it's a worksheet event - not a workbook event. If you still can't find it, get out of the VBE and on the sheet tab at the bottom of Excel, right-click and select `View Code` - that will take you straight there.